# JavaScript authentication with c# sdk. What happens on server?

Tags: facebook, authentication, facebook-c#-sdk

I have made a JS authentication on local server, and it also went fluently on server side. As I understood the sdk cached up with the JS auth and all went well. But When I have uploaded this on server, the IsAuthorized method returned false after the JS auth. Why could that happend? And how does the sdk handle the JS auth?

Answer (score 0):

Check your website url in the facebook app configuration page. Maybe the domain is now different?